# Thunderbird - Is there a way to fetch new email more often than once in a minute?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

By default Thunderbird fetches mail every ten minutes for each account. I haven't been able to set a lower delay than one minute, `0` defaults to `1` and decimals (`,`; `.`) can't be used.

[image]

Is there a way to set Thunderbird to be constantly searching for mail (IMAP)?

Comment: What platform? I suppose this is about POP? Make it clear!

Comment: @SPRBRN No, about IMAP. Should be universal to all platforms, but I personally I only use Windows and Linux.

Comment: Why would you need a synchronization that runs more often than once a minute?

Comment: @Seth: I have probably made a mistake, IMAP should be constant and "check for new messages" are only for the POP protocol, potentially.

Answer (score 1):

So it's IMAP. I thought IMAP does continuously check for new messages. It's only the syncing that is not continuous. Syncing means downloading the mails for quick local search.

Maybe you can test this by setting the sync to 10 minutes, then send a message and see if you see it appear. It will show only headers, and when you open it, it downloads.

See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/imap-synchronization

(Disclaimer: I'm no IMAP expert, but this is how I understand it works.)

Answer (score -1):

You would have to look into `about:config` to set a smaller value (if possible).

If you look [at this Mozilla KB article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/IMAP#Push_support) you can see that Thunderbird also supports Push Notifications if your IMAP server supports the appropriate commands (`IDLE`). My guess would be that the server also needs to be configured to notify connected clients of updates.

Comment: I believe that IMAP folders are always up to date and Thunderbird settings in the question only touch POP accounts. See this related answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/263858